# how should a message look like to be a response

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I have read and followed the example in http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-correlation

I have a spring-integration server

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
    id="socketserver"
    type="server"
    port="30124"
    using-nio="true"
    mapper="mapper"
    deserializer="jsonSerializer"
    serializer="jsonSerializer"
    single-use="false"/>
```

with this mapper from above [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-correlation):

```
<bean id="mapper"
  class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper">
<constructor-arg name="messageConverter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.support.converter.MapMessageConverter">
        <property name="headerNames">
            <list>
                <value>correlationId</value>
                <value>sequenceNumber</value>
                <value>sequenceSize</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
```

with inbound and outbound adapter

```
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundServer"
    channel="inputChannel"
    connection-factory="socketserver"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundServer"
    channel="outputChannel"
    connection-factory="socketserver"/>

<int:channel id="inputChannel"/>
<int:channel id="outputChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel"
           output-channel="outputChannel"
           ref="echoService"
           method="test"/>

<bean id="echoService" class="com.example.HelloReply" />
```

I'm sending Messages to a connected client with

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map msgMap = new HashMap();
msgMap.put("message", "test");
headers.put(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, <the connection id>);
headers.put("correlationId", "boo");
headers.put("sequenceNumber", 100);
headers.put("sequenceSize", 5);
Message<Map> msg = new GenericMessage<Map>(msgMap, headers);

MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();

Message reply = template.sendAndReceive(outputChannel, msg);
```

The last line blocks forever, because I can't figure out how to reply to that message properly from my legacy client (telnet).

The sent message is:

```
{"headers":{"sequenceNumber":101,"sequenceSize":5,"correlationId":"boo"},"payload":{"message":"test"}}
```

I thought that it would be the correlationId and the same sequenceNumber to match so I tried to response from client to the server with

```
{"headers":{"sequenceNumber":101,"sequenceSize":5,"correlationId":"boo"},"payload":{"result":"OK"}}
```

But it is interpreted as a new inbound message, not recognized as an answer for the initial send-message.

So what does sendAndReceive expect and is there some documentation/specification for that special usecase (sendAndReceive communication with non-spring clients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by

> channels "sendAndReceive"

?

Which APIs are you using? Unless you use a gateway, you are responsible for reply correlation.

The [TCP Client-Server Multiplex Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex) shows one technique (an aggregator) to correlate replies when not using a gateway.

Show your complete configuration (edit the question, don't add in a comment; it doesn't render well).

**EDIT**:

The framework can't do the correlation for you automatically (with `template.sendAndReceive()`). It doesn't know anything about your custom headers and, in any case, there's no way to get a reference to the automatic reply queue in the template for this message.

You have to write your own code to do the correlation.

```
template.send(...);
// wait for incoming message with the same correlation id
```

For example, you could use, say, a `Map<String, BlockingQueue>`, keyed by the correlation id and `poll` for the response.

Invoke another method in the class via a `<service-activator/>` and `put` the reply into the `BlockingQueue` for the correlation id. You could also use a map of `QueueChannel`s.

This use case (block the thread waiting for some asynchronous event) has come up several times and we are [considering adding a component to make things easier](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3736).

Comment: Thx for your reply. I edit the question, hopefully it is better to understand now. I know that I'm responsible for reply but I don't know what to reply.

Comment: Ah ok, then i have misinterpreted the documentation. I thought there is a standardized way having the correct headers in send and receive.

Thank you very much for your explaination.