# how to make sync from two machine request for spring integration?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-integration

[image]

This picture is my situation. I want to compose two transfer server. In the picture, two machine is it. When I call Transfer server by gateway, I will get a Message both adapter in Transfer Server. But, I don't think how to sync request and response Message.

How to slove this problem?

Comment: thank you gary:)
I'm not familiar with stack overflow because I'm first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with a gateway; the response has to come back on the same socket - that's how the framework correlates the response with the request.

You could do it with a outbound and inbound adapters on the sending system, but you would need something in the data to correlate the response with the request.

You're pretty much on your own for that.

You could use the [MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-headers) and JSON to add header information; but it would need to be propagated somehow across all the services involved.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I will change gateway to two adapter. But, I want to sync request with response.(it likes amqpTemplate's sendAndReceive Method) I thank when I call outbound adapter, maybe I should add listener to inbound adapter. but, I dont't think how to....

Comment: aha! i got this page. I will try this way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841348/how-should-a-message-look-like-to-be-a-response

Comment: Also see [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex) which uses an aggregator to wait for the reply. There is also a new [barrier](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#barrier) component which might help.